# On the topological properties and measure of $\{(A,B)\in M(n,\mathbb R)\times M(n,\mathbb R) : \det (A+B)=\det(A)+\det(B)\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, metric-spaces, linear-transformations, lebesgue-measure

For $n\ge 2$ , let $T(n):=\{(A,B)\in M(n,\mathbb R)\times M(n,\mathbb R) : \det (A+B)=\det(A)+\det(B)\}$ .

I can see that $T(n)$ is closed and non-compact in the usual norm of $M(n,\mathbb R)^2 \cong \mathbb R^{2n^2}$ . My questions are :

(1) Is $T(n)$ connected  or path connected ?

(2) Is the Lebesgue measure of $T(n)$ zero ?

(3) Is the interior of $T(n)$ empty ?

Comment: In the places in which $T(n)$ is smooth it is locally an intersection of coordinate hyperplanes. Therefore (2) and (3) hold there. The place where it is singular is given by the vanishing of a larger ideal. Apply the same argument for the smooth part of the singular set. Then by Noetherianity of the ring of polynomials of $n^2$ variables you eventually finish.

Comment: (1) If $(A,B)\in T(n)$, then $(tA,tB)\in T(n)$ since $det(tA+tB)=t^ndet(A+B)$ and $det(tA)=t^ndet(A)$ and $det(tB)=t^ndet(B)$. Therefore, $(A,B)$ is connected to $(0,0)$ inside of $T(n)$ by the path $t\mapsto (tA,tB)$.

Comment: @orole: ah great ... can you say anything about the connectedness of $T(n)\setminus \{(0,0)\}$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a bit long for a comment but not very deep: the anser to 2 is yes, from which it follows that the answer to 3 is yes as well. For 2: it is not just closed in the ordinary topology, but even in the Zariski-toplogy: it is the zero-set of a polynomial function. The only way that can have positive measure is if it is the enitre space, so it suffices to show that there is a point $(A, B)$ not of this form. This is not particularly hard.

Question 1 is interesting, though!

Comment: Indeed I was gonna make the same remark as an edit , $M(n,\mathbb R)^2$ is naturally linearly isomorphic with $\mathbb R^{2n^2}$ which hen you restrict to $T(n)$ gives the zero set of a polynomial. since linear isomorphism is Lipschitz, hence $T(n)$ has zero measure ....